# How to random access a magento collection

Tags: magento

I would like to access any element of a magento collection by its "index". i know that i can sort magento collections and filter them by calling `$collection->addFieldToFilter()` and `$collection->setOrder()` so if I set the order and I know how many elements I have is there a way to access the elements randomly? I would assume the functionality exists given that there are methods for `getFirstItem` and `getLastItem`.

The context of my problem is that i would like to be able to access up to ten elements back into a history of entries that are saved to the database, think command line with up and down arrow keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done in a single line, **but** you can fetch the internal `_items` array Magento users to store individual objects in a collection with

```
$items = $collection->getItems();
```

From there, `$items` is just a simple PHP array — access randomly as you wish.